# How do I find the file handles that my process has opened in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, file-io

When we perform a fork in Unix, open file handles are inherited, and if we don't need to use them we should close them. However, when we use libraries, file handles may be opened for which we do not have access to the handle. How do we check for these open file handles?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the libraries are opening files you don't know about, how do you know they don't need them after a fork? Unexported handles are an internal library detail, if the library wants them closed it will register an atfork() handler to close them. Walking around behind some piece of code closing its file handles behind its back will lead to subtle hard to debug problems since the library will error unexpectedly when it attempts to work with a handle it knows it opened correctly, but did not close.

Answer (score 18):

In Linux you can check `/proc/<pid>/fd` directory - for every open fd there will be a file, named as handle. I'm almost sure this way is non-portable.

Alternatively you can use `lsof` - available for Linux, AIX, FreeBSD and NetBSD, according to `man lsof`.

Answer (score 18):

You can do from a shell:

`lsof -P -n -p _PID_`

Where *PID* is your process pid.

Comment: What is the point of doing it on the shell? How am I supposed to get into my forked child process to close it?

Comment: @sep: this answer is maybe not the best when considering the description of your problem, but it sure nails the actual question. So, thank you Felipe for helping me find the handles of my process :)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned on @Louis Gerbarg's answer, the libraries are probably expecting the file handles to be kept open on `fork()` (which is supposed to be, after all, an almost identical copy of the parent process).

The problem most people have is on the `exec()` which often follows the `fork()`. Here, the correct solution is for the library which created the handles to mark them as close-on-exec (`FD_CLOEXEC`).

On libraries used by multithread programs, there is a race condition between a library creating a file handle and setting `FD_CLOEXEC` on it (another thread can `fork()` between both operations). To fix that problem, [`O_CLOEXEC`](http://udrepper.livejournal.com/20407.html) was introduced in the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you don't really need to care a whole lot about the open file descriptors you don't know about.  If you know you're not going to write to them again, closing them is a good idea and doesn't hurt - you just did a fork() after all, the fds are open twice.  But likewise, if you leave them open , they won't bother you either - after all, you don't know about them, you presumably won't be randomly writing to them.

As for what your third-party libraries will do, it's a bit of a toss-up either way.  Some probably don't expect to run into a situation with a fork(), and might end up accidentally writing to the same fd from two processes without any synchronization.  Others probably don't expect to have you closing their fds on them.  You'll have to check.  This is why it's a bad idea to randomly open a file descriptor in a library and not give it to the caller to manage.

All that said, in the spirit of answering the original question, there isn't a particularly good way.  You can call `dup()` or `dup2()` on a file descriptor; if it's closed, the call will fail with `EBADF`.  So you can say:

```
int newfd = dup(oldfd);
if (newfd > 0)
{
    close(newfd);
    close(oldfd);
}
```

but at that point you're just as well off saying `close(oldfd)` in the first place and ignoring any EBADFs.

Assuming you still want to take the nuclear option of closing everything, you then need to find the maximum number of open file descriptors possible.  Assuming 1 to 65,535 is not a good idea.  First of all, fds start at 0, of course, but also there's no particular upper limit defined.  To be portable, POSIX's `sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX)` should tell you, on any sane POSIX system, though strictly speaking it's optional.  If you're feeling paranoid, check the return value for -1, though at that point you mostly have to fall back on a hardcoded value anyway (1024 should be fine unless you're doing something extremely weird).  Or if you're fine with being Linux-specific, you can dig around in /proc.

Don't forget to not close fds 0, 1, and 2 - that can really confuse things.

Comment: Well, generally you don't care until you reach the limy and start getting too many open files errors.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what other people have said about closing random files being dangerous.  You might end up filing some pretty interesting bug reports for all of your third-party tools.

That said, if you *know* you won't need those files to be open, you can always walk through all of the valid file descriptors (1 to 65535, IIRC) and close everything you don't recognize.

Comment: You can use the getdtablesize(2) call to get the number of entries in the process's file descriptor table.

Answer (score 0):

Reasonable libraries will always have functions which free whatever resources (eg. file handles) they have allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a link, but it seems helpful: [How many open files?](http://www.netadmintools.com/art295.html) at netadmintools.com. It seems to use /proc investigations to learn about a process' open files, not sure if that is the only way or if there is an API. Parsing files for this type of information can be a bit ... messy. Also, /proc might be deprecated too, something to check for.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a design issue ? Is it possible for your process to fork before initializing the libs that open those files ?